# JDateChooser display language

Tags: java, swing, date, jcalendar, jdatechooser

I'am using `JCalendar`'s 1.4  `JDateChooser` so I ask if it is possible to change display names for months and days of weeks without having to change the source code, or, since I never looked the source code, is it complicated to change it even if it can be changed. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some example code of what you've tried?

Comment: do you want to change font ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`JCalendar`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jcalendar/info) responds correctly to [supported locales](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java8locales-2095355.html). For example, the locale illustrated below is specified on the command line:

```
java -Duser.language=fr -Duser.country=FR -cp build/classes DateDemo
```

[image]

Additional localized text properties are found in the source code:

```
src/com/toedter/calendar/jcalendar_*
```

For unsupported locales, consider [*ICU4J Locale Service Provider*](http://userguide.icu-project.org/icu4j-locale-service-provider).