# Change language at runtime (using internationalization "tool")

Tags: java, swing, internationalization

I saw some topics with the same question as I have but they are old and none of the answers is good for me.

So I have this application in Java that uses Swing. I've implemented internationalization designing the UI and now I need something that can change the language (Locale maybe) of the application and refresh the components of UI. Like, hits the button "change language" and the app change the language.

Is this possible without a restart and using only ResourceBundle?

Cheers

[EDIT]

I tried this:

```
Locale aLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("pt").setRegion("PT").build();

Locale.setDefault(aLocale);
this.dispose();
new Window("Fisica").setVisible(true);
```

This "solution" has something wrong?

Comment: What is the "something wrong" that your attempt at a solution seems to exhibit?

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26666649/230513)?

Comment: @MarsAtomic I don't know, maybe it's not a good practice to do the last 2 lines of my "solution"?

Comment: Someone can give a help on this please?